# An issue in posting data from an Android app to a PHP website

Tags: php, android

I have developed an Android app to post data to a PHP website.

Everything looks fine. It must post data to http://tayyab001.base.pk/kami.php but it's not working. No errors, no issues but it's not working.

logcat shows everything fine.

Where is the issue?

```
package com.latlongapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button sendButton;

    EditText msgTextField;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         // make message text field object
        msgTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msgTextField);
        // make send button object
        sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    }

    class SendTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                  // get the message from the message text box
                String msg = msgTextField.getText().toString();  

                // make sure the fields are not empty
                if (msg.length()>0)
                {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://http://tayyab001.base.pk/kami.php");
                 try {
                   List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
                   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", msg));
                   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                   httpclient.execute(httppost);
                   msgTextField.setText(""); // clear text box
                 } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 }

                }
                else
                {
                    // display message if text fields are empty
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"All field are required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
             return null;
        }}

     public void send(View v)
        {
         new SendTask().execute();
        }

}
```

PHP SCript being used is

```
<?php
// get the "message" variable from the post request
// this is the data coming from the Android app
$message=$_POST["message"]; 
// specify the file where we will save the contents of the variable message
$filename="androidmessages.html";
// write (append) the data to the file
file_put_contents($filename,$message."<br />",FILE_APPEND);
// load the contents of the file to a variable
$androidmessages=file_get_contents($filename);
// display the contents of the variable (which has the contents of the file)
echo $androidmessages;
?>
```

XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView
    android:text="Message"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    /> 

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/msgTextField"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<Button
    android:text="Send"
    android:id="@+id/sendButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="send"
    /> 

manifest

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />


        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.latlongapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Is the file writable by the server?

Comment: i have no idea about it.

Comment: I just tested your code and it's throwing an IOException.  Add log outputs to your catch blocks.

Comment: Make sure you remove any calls to the UI thread in your doInBackground().

Comment: You wrote "http" twice in the URL you specified for your HttpPost objct.

Comment: @JDJ thanks for response. i tried again but still unsuccessful. can you please modify it  correctly...

Comment: Did you remove the two "http"'s?

Comment: I works.  I just posted the answer to your website here: http://tayyab001.base.pk/kami.php

Comment: great. thank you very much.
so nice of you man..

Comment: Glad I could help and good luck with your app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57587/discussion-between-user2590541-and-jdj).

Comment: @JDJ its working but app also just closed after clicking button...

Comment: Did you use the code I posted below?  It's not closing for me.

Comment: now its perfect. thanks alot and so nice of you.
stay blessed ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should remove all calls to the UI thread from `doInBackground()`.

But the main error is that you wrote "http" twice when creating your `HttpPost` object.

Try this code.  It works because I just posted the answer to your website with it :)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{   
    Button sendButton;

    EditText msgTextField;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         // make message text field object
        msgTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msgTextField);

        // make send button object
        sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    }

    class SendTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
    {
        String msg = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            msg = msgTextField.getText().toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
        {   
            // make sure the fields are not empty
            if (msg.length() > 0)
            {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://tayyab001.base.pk/kami.php");

                 try 
                 {
                     List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
                     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", msg));

                     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                     httpclient.execute(httppost);                         
                 } 
                 catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
                 {
                     Log.d("MainActivityTest", "ClientProtocolException caught.");
                 } 
                 catch (IOException e) 
                 {
                     Log.d("MainActivityTest", "IOException caught. " + e.toString());
                 }
            }
            else
            {
                // display message if text fields are empty
                Log.d("MainActivityTest", "All fields are required.");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            msgTextField.setText("");
        }           
    }

     public void send(View v)
     {
         new SendTask().execute();
     }
}
```